# Functor variadic template pack expansion for empty pack gives different results in clang++ and g++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

The following code [compiles successfully with *clang++ 3.8.0* and fails to compile with *g++ 7.2.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74d7c5e4e8f0872f) (with the `-std=c++14 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors` compilation flags):

```
auto foo = [](auto functor, auto... argument_functors)
{
    functor(argument_functors()...);
};

auto do_nothing = [](auto...) {};


int main()
{
    foo(do_nothing);
}
```

*g++* error messages:

> ```
> main.cpp: In instantiation of '<lambda(auto:1, auto:2 ...)> [with auto:1 = <lambda(auto:3, ...)>; auto:2 = {}]':
> main.cpp:11:16:   required from here
> main.cpp:3:9: error: no match for call to '(<lambda(auto:3, ...)>) ()'
>   functor(argument_functors()...);
>   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> main.cpp:6:29: note: candidate: template<class auto:3> <lambda(auto:3, ...)>::operator decltype (((const<lambda(auto:3, ...)>*)((const<lambda(auto:3, ...)>* const)0))->operator()(static_cast<auto:3&&>(<anonymous>))) (*)(auto:3, ...)() const <deleted>
>  auto do_nothing = [](auto...) {};
>                              ^
> main.cpp:6:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> main.cpp:3:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>   functor(argument_functors()...);
>   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> main.cpp:6:29: note: candidate: template<class auto:3> <lambda(auto:3, ...)>
>  auto do_nothing = [](auto...) {};
>                              ^
> main.cpp:6:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> main.cpp:3:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>   functor(argument_functors()...);
>   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Which compiler behavior is standard compliant?

Comment: I can tell you it works with vc 19.12 as well.

Comment: It compiles [from clang 3.6 up to clang 5.0](https://godbolt.org/g/1L1hpb), so at least they think they're doing it right! That'd be a first approximation to whether it's correct behaviour.

Comment: @hnefatl There's no need for a return from `main`. `main` is special.

Comment: @Barry Oh awesome, I didn't know that - thanks for teaching me something new. Just found a related SO question that verifies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is gcc bug [64095](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64095).

From [[dcl.fct]/18](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct-18):

> There is a syntactic ambiguity when an ellipsis occurs at the end of a *parameter-declaration-clause* without a preceding comma. In this case, the ellipsis is parsed as part of the *abstract-declarator* if the type of the parameter either names a template parameter pack that has not been expanded **or contains `auto`**; otherwise, it is parsed as part of the *parameter-declaration-clause*.

Basically, `(T...)` in a parameter list can be interpreted as either:

- One unnamed parameter of type `T`, and an ellipsis.
- A function parameter pack, with types of the template parameter pack `T`.

The disambiguation rule is supposed to prefer the latter if `T` is a template parameter pack or `auto`, but gcc is choosing to interpret this as an ellipsis parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much! So this situation has no relation to functors. My bad, I couldn't minimize the MWE sufficiently.